# how to Create a bubble chart in jqplot with angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, jqplot

I already created pie, bar and donut chart in jqplot with angularjs, but trying bubble chart it's not working. please anyone can help to figure out this

[Sample code][1]

```
  [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/JRB0atAAVOPqAOWNoQIu?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved your problem.Here is the solution.

```
    $scope.bubbleChartData = [[[11, 123, 1236, "Acura"], [45, 92, 1067, "Alfa Romeo"],[24, 104, 1176, "AM General"], [50, 23, 610, "Aston Martin Lagonda"],[18, 17, 539, "Audi"], [7, 89, 864, "BMW"], [2, 13, 1026, "Bugatti"]]];
```

Comment: Oh. sorry its my bad.. i forget to add into array :(

Comment: It's okay no problem.